# Books or readings on topics like differentiating a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I recently encountered an increasing number of questions that requires operations like differentiating a matrix wrt a vector etc. I've never had any lecture on this and can't find any book relating to this sort of subjects. Would anyone be so kind and recommend me some readings on this please?
Many thanks

Comment: http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf, http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf, http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf,